# Как получить последние несколько элементов массива по клику меняя массив

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Как получить последние несколько элементов массива по клику меняя массив
например есть:

```
let А = ['a','b','c','d','c','d'];
let B = [];
```

я хочу, чтобы по вызову функции бралось 2 последних элемента из массива А (один клик +2 элемента, тоесть для переноса всех 6 эл должно понадобиться 3 вызова функции) и переносились первыми в массив B.

например: 
1)

```
   let А = ['a','b','c','d'];
   let B = ['c','d'];
```

2)

```
   let А = ['a','b'];
   let B = ['c','d','c','d'];
```

3)

```
   let А = [];
   let B = ['a','b','c','d','c','d'];
```

уточню, что знаю о функции .splice()
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let arr2 = [];

const slicer = () => {
  arr2 = [...arr1.slice(-2), ...arr2];
  arr1 = arr1.slice(0, arr1.length - 2);
};

slicer();
console.log("one", arr1, arr2);
slicer();
console.log("two", arr1, arr2);
slicer();
console.log("three", arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: **...и переносились первыми в массив B** - а здесь добавляются справа.

Comment: вы код запускали? работает идентично вашему варианту

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
const arr2 = [];

const swissKnife = () => {
    arr2.unshift(...arr1.splice(-2));
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    swissKnife();
    console.log(arr1, arr2);
}
```